# How to handle scroll in specific element?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, scroll, element

I'm using Element UI component in Vue.js and would like to add scroll management function to implement infinite scroll.

[This is a code of screenshot: Please take a look Example section]
http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/container

I tried the following code but infiniteScroll method was not called even if I scroll this section.

`<el-main @scroll="infiniteScroll">......</el-main>`

Also, I tried below as well, but it was not working because this page has two scrolls (in nav/content) and want to call infiniteScroll method when content is scrolled only.

```
created: function () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.infiniteScroll);
},
destroyed: function () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.infiniteScroll);
}
```

Do you guys have the best solution?

[image]

Comment: Your Jsfiddle link is broken

Comment: @Muhammad Osama -Thank you for letting me know. I have changed the URL.

Comment: You have the right idea in your second attempt. but you are binding the event listener to the wrong element. Add a `ref` attribute to your main `el-main` element, find the `content` and bind the scroll event listener to that element instead

Comment: @Chinonso Chukwuogor Thank you for your comment. I tried your solution but had the following error:

`"TypeError: this.$refs.myInfiniteScroll.addEventListener is not a function"`

I changed it to `id` from `ref` as Nomis's suggest, then it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<el-main @scroll="infiniteScroll">......</el-main>` doesn't work because when binding an event on a component, Vue **listens for custom events by default**.

[If you want to listen for a native event you have to use the `.native` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components):

`<el-main @scroll.native="infiniteScroll">......</el-main>`

Check [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/gupsy1xb/)

Comment: -Thank you very much. your answer is the simplest one! This is really good to know!

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Chinonso Chukwuogor in the comments, you should attach the listener to the scrolling element you want. Something like that should work :

`<el-main id="myInfiniteScroll">......</el-main>`

`document.getElementById('myInfiniteScroll').addEventListener('scroll', this.infiniteScroll);`

If it doesn't, it's more a matter of what is the infiniteScroll method.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried to use `ref` but had a following error
`"TypeError: this.$refs.myInfiniteScroll.addEventListener is not a function"`

I changed it to `id` that you suggested to me, then it 's working! Thank you again!